# How would a medieval society treat and view Giants?

Tags: fantasy-races, psychology, interspecies-relations

Giants in my world are fairly human-looking, besides being 14ft tall on average. Giants are unable to normally communicate (due to their constant heavy breathing) but instead communicate through stomping their feet. Giants can often predict earthquakes because of how sensitive their feet are to vibrations, which also allows them to better understand other giants. It's highly debated on whether giants are as intelligent or below humans, because giants can't really express themselves easily due to their non spoken language and most humans don't understand it. Giants also aren't very advance, having only a very basic level of farming which is just herding wild cattle, and because they don't really fight wars with each other they just have basic spears. There's two types of giants, Frost Giants (everything above sums them up pretty well) and the Islander Giants which are about 2ft shorter then Frost Giants but have more well defined muscles and live in the tropics sailing from island to island. Giants tend to keep to themselves and both types only form small family units, and aren't exactly aggressive but will defend themselves fiercely.

Comment: You are the author and ultimate authority over your world. Have people treat them however you want.

Answer (score 12):

## The same way we treat elephants

Elephants are large creatures which can grow to be 13 feet tall which can't speak english. They're of another race. This has led to predictable treatment.

1. They are enslaved for labour and war.
2. They are used by rich kings to show off their wealth.
3. They're hunted as megafauna for their meat and body parts.
4. They are put in circuses to do tricks for us.
5. They are bred to make them more docile slaves.

Giants would be treated the same way. They're poorly organized and so can't resist enslavement, have families so they can probably be tamed by making a human take the role of the parent.

Comment: Elephants that can be trained for more complex tasks, EVEN BETTER! Like, elephants are limited in that you can't really teach them to use tools effectively, and you can't blackmail them into complicity by having their mom locked up.  Sure, Giants are far more risky, but also have a far higher reward if trained and utilized correctly. With the right brainwashing you might not even need to blackmail them, just convince them you're better and by god-given right (or whatever giants believe in) get to "lead" them and their lives

Comment: @Hobbamok I've seen several videos of elephants using tools. If you can't teach them to use tools effectively, you probably haven't taught them what the tools are _for_.

Answer (score 8):

Giants have skills they would be payed for, but they'll pay a lot back also.. for the unintended damages they inflict on other man's properties, with their communications.. *"sorry your house collapsed, I only made a joke"*

**People would be interested in their work force**

These giants would be nice workers in agriculture. They don't need oxen to plough, or an axe to fell a tree. In the cities, they would come in handy to help moving furniture..  build churches, like putting the [Baphomet statues](https://www.google.com/search?q=baphomet%20statue%20notre%20dame) on the ridges:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

They would probably be very afraid of giants because they would have a superhuman strenght and a nedieval society do not have enough powerful weapons and technology to take the giants down.

However even if the giants were nice people they could not live among "normal" people due to the extreme morphology  and size difference. Both would be  needed to treated and viewed as different alien species.